# Error while loading shared library : librun.so

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a compiled script (it's some utility) and the source code of which is unavailable. As soon as I run the script this error shows up:

```
error while loading shared libraries: librun.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have faced these kind of errors in past which had different solutions. I tried all as per my knowledge and..

1. librun.so is there in lib folder of my application
2. It is symbolic link and pointing to correct version
3. librun.so is available in path variable
4. changed .profile to look for the required library
5. changed permissions and checked
6. "which librun.so" is also returning the presence of that library

still this error shows up.
What can be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic linker is unable to find `librun.so` during runtime linking of shared libraries. Try adding the path of directory containing `librun.so` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable when starting the application script.

Comment: Thank you sir. I tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH` . PATH variable contains the path to my library. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I restarted the session and that error is gone. Same error for another library showed up. So this problem is solved. Now I can take care of rest I guess. Thank you good sir.

Comment: @jigar Does `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` now contain the path to `librun.so` or the path to the directory **containing** `librun.so`?